# How to properly riggify character`s face

Tags: rigging

I"m trying to riggify my character's face after successfully riggifying the whole body, but it seems that it doesn't work out for me. Can I have some kind of guidance what to do.

In short, I've been trying this method with a tutorial of a guy on YouTube (It's called "Facial Rigging With Bendy Bones")and nothing happened.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=bk6DxlQR" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/bk6DxlQR/)

Comment: it's because of the Stretch To constraints, what are the bones they are supposed to stretch to?

Comment: sORRY i DIDNT UNDERSTAND

Comment: you've give a Stretch To constraint to your eyes bones, what is it for? where are there targets? Also, could you please be more specific, what doesn't work in your rigging?

Comment: Like,I use this plugin called "Control Bones" and it just gives me out the errors when I try using them

Comment: @ViktorOlivye you should edit your question and add the error message, what you have done, in which mode is active, etc. It's hard to help you and further readers with so few informations.